# Adding the Google Contacts v3 API to my project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, google-contacts-api

Please forgive me if this sounds like a simple question but I am getting myself confused.

I have a Visual Basic application that uses the **Google Calendar v3 API** and it has been fully operational for several months. The **authentication** is all working etc..

Now I am wanting to extend the cababilities of my project to include **contact** details. I intially found this:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact

It provides several examples, although they are C#. Eg:

```
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
// ...
    RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME");
    // Add authorization token.
    // ...
    ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
// ...
```

In my Visual Basic application I have this header section instead:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Xml
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
```

I am struggling to locate the **contacts** component. In my NuGet packager this is what I have currently installed:

[image: Installed Nuget packages]

I have tried to find the **Google.Calendar** or **Google.Apis.Calendar** and can't find it. It has been over a year since I setup the initial application to work with Google.Calendar.v3. What steps have I forgotten?

Thank you for your assistance with this!

**UPDATE**
I came across this webpage:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.GData.Contacts/

So I thought I would try executing the command in my NuGet Package Console, but this is the results:

```
Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

Package Manager Console Host Version 3.4.3.855

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package Google.GData.Contacts
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Google.GData.Contacts.2.2.0' with respect to project 'CommunityTalks', targeting 'native,Version=v0.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Google.GData.Contacts.2.2.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Google.GData.Contacts.2.2.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Google.GData.Contacts.2.2.0'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json.4.0.5.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json.4.0.5.nupkg 21ms
Installing Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.5.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.4.0.5' does not exist in project 'CommunityTalks'
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.4.0.5' does not exist in folder 'D:\My Programs\CommunityTalks\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more 
information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.GData.Contacts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

So I am not sure what is going on. Whether I am downloading the wrong thing or what. But what I do know is that the Google.Calendar.v3 is installed OK and operational.

**SUCCESS**

Looks like I may have resolved this accidently:

[image: Nuget Settings]

I had to set the project property before I executed the **PM** command:

```
Install-Package Google.GData.Contacts
```

Please let me know if I came up with the wrong solution (or the right one!)